# Why would Mexico be inclined to help pay for Trump's wall?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, borders, mexico, trump-wall

I'm reading [a news article](http://www.npr.org/2016/11/09/501451368/here-is-what-donald-trump-wants-to-do-in-his-first-100-days) about Trump's plan for his first 100 days.  The following discusses his controversial "build a wall" proposal:

> He also laid out his plan for working with Congress to introduce 10
>   pieces of legislation that would repeal Obamacare, fund the
>   construction of a wall at the Southern border (**with a provision that
>   Mexico would reimburse the U.S.**)...

I'm curious about the provision that Mexico would "reimburse" the U.S.  On what grounds would the U.S. expect Mexico to help us with this?  Wouldn't Mexico just shrug their shoulders and say, "You're the ones who wanted the wall - why would we want to help pay for it?"

Comment: Previous [question](http://politics.stackexchange.com/q/12652/4666).

Comment: While I think the answer to the "duplicate" ultimately answers the question--"reimburse" not meaning we're sending them a bill, but that we're just taking the money as it gets sent into Mexico because reasons; which is a method bound to dry up the available money long before the project is completed, incidentally--, but as phrased the questions are distinct.  The duplicate wants to know the details of Trump's wall plan, whereas this question seems more concerned with the legal and political aspects of one country trying to charge another country for it's own projects.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy: (I'm the one who posted this question.)  I feel the same, this question is distinct.  I didn't feel strongly enough about it to ask for it to be reopened, but if you think others might find value in having this *specific* question answered, feel free to reopen.